# Текущий день плюс дни

Tags: cmd

Как добавить в текущий день + несколько дней? В батнике делаю так:
`set dt=%Date:~-10%

set /a dtDay=%dt:~0,2% 
set /a dtDay=%dtDay%+1 
echo %dtDay%`

Работает. Но когда вместо 1, пишу 2 или 3, выходить результат 32 или 33, а надо чтобы выходил 1 или 2. т.е. Например: сегодня 30/10/18 + 2 дня, будет 01/11/18.

Comment: В powershell можно использовать все возможности .NET, а в нем есть мощные методы работы с датами/временем.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прибавить или отнять день от текущей даты в командном языке Windows не такая уж тривиальная задача, так как если просто прибавить день ко взятому от даты числу возникает неоднозначность в плане выхода числа за пределы допустимого количества дней в месяце. При таком положении дел видится как минимум три варианта, один из которых вам уже озвучили в комментариях. Другой основам на элементарной математике и заключается в конвертировании текущей даты в т.н. *Julian Day*, с последующей манипуляцией над полученным значением. Иными словами:

```
@echo off
  setlocal
    <nul set /p "=Today is : "
    date /t
    <nul set /p "=Tomorrow : "
    call:shiftDate %date% + 1
    echo:%day%
    <nul set /p "=Yesterday: "
    call:shiftDate %date% - 1
    echo:%day%
    <nul set /p "=+63 days : "
    call:shiftDate %date% + 63
    echo:%day%
    <nul set /p "=Rnd. date: "
    call:shiftDate "31.12.2018" - 62
    echo:%day%
    pause
  endlocal
exit /b

:toJulianDay
  set /a "jdn=(1461*(%3+4800+(%2-14)/12))/4+(367*(%2-2-12*((%2-14)/12)))/12-(3*((%3+4900+(%2-14)/12)/100))/4+%1-32075"
exit /b

:fromJulianDay
  set /a "a=jdn+32044, b=(4*a+3)/146097, c=a-146097*b/4, d=(4*c+3)/1461, e=c-1461*d/4, m=(5*e+2)/153"
  set /a "dd=e-(153*m+2)/5+1, mm=m+3-12*(m/10), yy=100*b+d-4800+m/10"
  if %dd% lss 10 set "dd=0%dd%"
  if %mm% lss 10 set "mm=0%mm%"
  set "day=%dd%.%mm%.%yy%"
exit /b

:shiftDate
  set "d=%~1"
  2>nul set /a "dd=%d:~0,2%, mm=%d:~3,2%, yy=%d:~6,4%"
  call:toJulianDay %dd% %mm% %yy%
  set /a "jdn%~2=%~3"
  call:fromJulianDay
exit /b
```

После запуска этого примера вы получите следующий вывод в консоли (*все даты, за исключением последней, относительно текущего дня*):

```
Today is : 30.10.2018
Tomorrow : 31.10.2018
Yesterday: 29.10.2018
+63 days : 01.01.2019
Rnd. date: 30.10.2018
```

Еще один способ - взаимодействие с `mshta`.

```
@echo off
  setlocal
    call:dateshift 1 day
    echo:Tomorrow  : %day%
    call:dateshift 1 day past
    echo:Yesterday : %day%
  endlocal
exit /b

:dateshift
  set "s=mshta vbscript:Execute("CreateObject("
  set "s=%s%""Scripting.FileSystemObject"")"
  set "s=%s%.GetStandardStream(1).Write("
  set ^"e=):Close"^)"
  set "op=+"
  if /i "%~3" equ "past" set "op=-"
  for /f %%# in ('%s% Date%op%1 %e%') do set "%2=%%#"
exit /b
```

Есть и другие способы, но смысл описывать их здесь все представляется бесперспективным занятием.

Comment: greg zakharov, спасибо большое!!!

Comment: greg zakharov, не знаю почему, но Ваш скрипт на даты 07/11, 08/11, 09/11 работает неправильно. :( На другие даты, работает правильно.

Comment: @Cool_Dude. если внимательно посмотреть на код. можно заметить одну простую вещь: для корректной работы требуется указывать дату а) полностью, б) с расстановкой символов относительно текущей локали (или культуры). Иначе говоря. приведенные примеры правите на свое усмотрение в соответствии с конечной целью.

Comment: В коде используется системная дата же? Я без никаких изменений взял и проверил этот код. На разных "Текущее местоположение". Всё равно, на этих датах не работает...=(

Comment: @Cool_Dude, если вам принесут листок с "датой" 07/11, вы сможете однозначно сказать какой год имеется в виду? А сможете ли вы однозначно сказать что в записи 06/06 является днем, а что числом? Едва ли. поэтому и было оговорено, что в данном случае используется дата в русскоязычной локали вида DD.MM.YYYY. Постарайтесь вникнуть в код, если разберетесь для вас будет большим бонусом понимание принципов работы с датой в командной строке, не разбересь, увы.

Comment: Я код уже посмотрел. В коде берется дата системная. т.е. там конкретно идет 07.11.2018 или 08.11.2018 или 09.11.2018. Я это проверил на русскоязычной локали и на англоязычной тоже. Результат одинаковый.